# PHP buffer included file as anonymous function

Tags: php, include, buffer, anonymous-function

I have a kind of template file that may be called `filename.php`:

```
<h1>
  <?= $test . ' world'; ?>
</h1>
<p>
Some text
</p>
```

Then I have a function in an `index.php` file that looks like this?

```
<?php
function test($args) {
  $test = $args;
  include 'filename.php';
}

test('Hello');
test('Hello');
test('Hello');
```

This code works. It output the included data 3 times.

I can also use [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-contents.php) to get the output as a string if I want. However, that's not exactly what I want.

**Problem**

I can't figure out a way to only need to include the `filename.php` one time (now it's loaded 3 times). Because it accepts arguments it can't be returned as string. It needs to be returned as an anonymous function, I guess. Then I could buffer my template and still use it with new values.

Any creative ideas are welcome.

Comment: I think it's better to create a template string and `str_replace/preg_replace` values in it. But even in template engines you `include` subtemplate as many times as you need.

Comment: _“(now it's loaded 3 times)”_ -  so what …?

Comment: If you need a templating language, I would go for a tried and tested one. However, you could of course read the file contents of `filename.php` and do a `eval(' ?>' . $file_contents . '<?php ');`, see https://3v4l.org/70dgu :-)

Comment: @misorude In the real world They may be loaded 100 of times.

Comment: @jeroen I've heard that eval is bad and dangerous, but I will read more about it, thanks! =)

Comment: _“In the real world They may be loaded 100 of times”_ - oh, well in _that_ case - so what? Are you trying to fix any real, measurable issue here - or maybe rather just an imagined one?

Comment: Well, you want to *evaluate* your php script as php, what is what `include` does as well...

Comment: @misorude, the issue may also be that the real template file is very large...

Comment: That's not really a problem. Template (if it is a template) just shows data. If you show 100k lines of data - it's not a template problem, it's problem of application logic - you should use pagination, warm up cache or something else. So, there's nothing unusual to include a file as many times as you need.